# MPAndroidChart 3.0.1: understanding two concepts

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am having 2 problems with my MPAndroidChart 3.0.1 graphs and since I can't find the programatically answer I am trying to understand on a concept level how things work so I can try to workout my code. By the way my charts are time series with temperature as Y value and timestamps as X values.

Basically this is problem 1 that I don't understand. When I plot a chart, even if I don't set ANY xAxis value formatter, I get vertical grid lines that are not equally spaced, and are not exclusively marking my Y values. Please see:
[image]

So regarding this issue, my goal was to either have these lines equally spaced representing fixed time periods, OR, ONLY to mark my Y values, AND NOT random spots where I don't even have a Y value.

Then my issue number 2 that I would like to understand conceptually. I have a database with 2 columns, timestamps and temperature. When I import these values to the application, they come perfectly as they should be. Example:

```
I/App: Device 17AB05 | Timestamp 2017-02-27 22:09:55.0 | Temp 23.0
I/App: Device 17AB05 | Timestamp 2017-02-27 22:13:54.0 | Temp 21.0
I/App: Device 17AB05 | Timestamp 2017-02-27 22:17:44.0 | Temp 19.0
I/App: Device 17AB05 | Timestamp 2017-02-27 22:20:44.0 | Temp 24.0
I/App: Device 17AB05 | Timestamp 2017-02-27 22:28:44.0 | Temp 30.0
I/App: Device 17AB05 | Timestamp 2017-02-27 22:33:44.0 | Temp 27.0
```

Then I add these values as Entry to my LineChart, however, when plotted all the timestamps are messed up. For instance, my first temperature 23 degrees comes in chart with timestamp of 22:09:20 - therefore 33 seconds deviation. I thought that this could be to precision loss when converting timestamp to epoch and then back, however I confirmed it is not the case, my methods convert with precision back and forth. I really don't know why this happens.

If you have any idea of the whys of my issues 1 or 2 I would be really glad with an input.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Both issues were solved after I subtracted an offset from the epoch values, which allowed float to handle the remainder without messing up with date precision.